# Ionic.zlib stops compressing when the compressed file has reached 65536 bytes? - C#

Tags: c#, zlib

Hey, I'm having problems compressing files with Ionic.zlib, I'm very new to C# so the problem may be easily solvable.  If I compress a large file, let's say 500kb in size then once the compressed file has reached 65536 bytes it will stop, if I then decompress the file theres a lot of data missing :/.  I can fix this by setting the buffer to like 4,000,000, but I heard that it's best to have it set to 0x4000.

```
        ZlibStream compressor = new ZlibStream(gsc_stream, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.BestCompression, true);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[0x4000];
        Int32 n;

        int previous = Convert.ToInt32(zone.Position);

        while ((n = compressor.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            zone.Write(buffer, 0, n);

        }
        zone.Flush();
        compressor.Flush();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have it the other way around.
If you're trying to compress the file in the stream `gsc_stream` and write the result into the stream `zone` then correct code would be:

```
using (ZlibStream compressor = new ZlibStream(zone, CompressionMode.Compress, CompressionLevel.BestCompression, true))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x4000];
    int n;
    while ((n = gsc_stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        compressor.Write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    zone.Flush();
    compressor.Flush();
}
```

Comment: Doesn't even have the zlib header anymore, and it compresses parts of I file I didn't tell it to.  Hey at least it done more than 65536 bytes.

Comment: Top part isn't compressed in the zone, as soon as the first gsc_stream is wrote to the file, the rest of the file from there on is compressed, except the start at where it done this is before the position zone was even at, and as I said, there's no zlib header at all.

Comment: @Levi `gsc_stream` should be something like: `gsc_stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileToCompress);`

Comment: It's meant to open the gsc_stream, and write a compressed version of it to the zone, here's my whole function for writing the gsc files to the zone.  Added it to first post.

Comment: I done what you said and set the flushmode to partial, but now it's only compressing 75k bytes :/.

Comment: @Levi cheers, care to share the solution for the sake of others with this problem? :)

Comment: What you said and
'compressor.FlushMode = FlushType.Partial;'